# How to ignore dashes or hyphens in JS comparisons

Tags: javascript, operators

I want to compare two input values on a page.
One input value is always entered with hyphens as spaces. ie "first-value"
The other input value is never entered with hyphens as spaces. ie "first value"

"first-test" == "first test"
this views them as different. Is there an operator that would view these as the same?

Comment: replace it.....

Comment: have you tried *removing* the hyphens and dashes, or alternatively *replacing* them with spaces?

Comment: "first-test" and "first test" are examples of values from an input. The user is inputing this data and saving. I want to compare it. One is a url slug so it needs dashes, the other is just a string of words with no dashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashes may come in more varieties thank you'd expect. Especially if people copy/paste their input from MS Word and the likes. For example, would you consider - or ‐ or ‑ or ‒ or – or — or ― all to be dashes? (they're all different unicode characters)

If the parts that you care about are only alphanumeric, you're better off stripping away everything else.

Do you regard `first-test` and `firs ttest` to be equal? If yes, then simply removing all non-alphanumeric chars will do:

```js
str1 = str1.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,'');
str2 = str2.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,'');
var doMatch = (str1 == str2);
```

If no, then replace all non-alphanumeric parts with single spaces:

```js
str1 = str1.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi,' ');
str2 = str2.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi,' ');
// trim to ignore space at begin or end
str1 = str1.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
str2 = str2.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
var doMatch = (str1 == str2);
```

This also allows for people copy/pasting values with an accidental extra space at the end. Which sometimes happens but is barely noticeable, and could cause lots of headaches if you consider that different.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str1 = 'first-test';
var str2 = 'first test';
var doMatch = str1.replace('-', ' ') === str2.replace('-', ' '); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var variableWithHyphen = "variable-value-value";
var variable = "variable value value";

function areEqual(varOne, varTwo) {
  var hypen = new RegExp('-', 'g');
  return varTwo.replace(hypen, " ") === varOne.replace(hypen, " ");
}

alert(areEqual(variable, variableWithHyphen));
```